# nothing happens on libcloud create_node

Tags: amazon-ec2

I use libcloud to create a new node instance Amazon EC2.

conn.create_node returns me a valid instance and printing node.dict shows the expected values.

however when I check my EC2 dashboard the new machine does not appear there.

do I need my python app to stay open so that the node is actually created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it: the instance was actually created but for some reason the amazon did not show it even after refresh. logging out and in solved it.